# How to retrieve place images from Here Maps API?

Tags: maps, here-api

I am trying to figure out on how to get place images from here maps API. The documentation really sucks and is way too complicated.

I am using the below request:

```
$url = "https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=12.9716,77.5946&app_id=$AppID&app_code=$AppCode&cat=eat-drink,sights-museums,shopping,natural-geographical&size=50";
```

The response doesn't contain anything related to place images returned in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From explore response you only get usually the icon image. You should use the "href" attribute response for a POI to get all the details of a POI, if your appid has access the detail will contain images inside the "media" response attribute.

Comment: Hi Jithin, can you point me in the right direction? how to use the href? which API to use? Any link where its mentioned or sample code would be appreciated

Comment: hey..u r right, got it, thanx :), where is this thing mentioned in the documents?

Comment: The documentation here : https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/entrypoints-media-types.html does talk a bit about using href (place link)